# Find rows where ID matches and date is within X days

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Somewhat new to SQL and I'm running into a bit of issue with a project.  I have a table like this:

| ID | subscription_ID | renewal_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 11 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 12 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 12 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 5 | 13 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 |
| 6 | 13 | 2022-01-03 12:00:00 |

My goal is to return rows where the subscription_ID matches and the start_date is within or equal to a certain # of days (hours would work as well).  For instance, I'd like rows where subscription_ID matches and the start_date is within or equal to 1 day such that my results from the table above would be:

| ID | subscription_ID | renewal_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 11 | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 |
| 3 | 12 | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 12 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 |

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated--thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `where the subscription_ID matches` ? You want `subscription_ID` that are more than one and the first start_date of the row is equal or +1 to the last date of the same `subscription_ID`  ?

Comment: Check the answer if it helps

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry!  Still working through proper jargon.  Maybe if I re-word start_date to renewal_date it will make more sense.  Subscriptions are 30 days in length but some appear to be renewing earlier than 30 days (specifically on back-to-back days) and I need to identify them. So a result might look like:

| ID | subscription_ID | renewal_date |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1  | 11    | 2022-01-01 |
| 2  | 11    | 2022-01-02 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly maybe you are trying something like:

```
select t.*
from test_tbl t 
join  ( SELECT subscription_id
     , MAX(diff) max_diff
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.subscription_id
            , DATEDIFF(MIN(y.start_date),x.start_date) diff
         FROM test_tbl x 
         JOIN test_tbl y ON y.subscription_id = x.subscription_id 
         AND y.start_date > x.start_date 
        GROUP  BY x.subscription_id , x.start_date
     ) z
 GROUP BY subscription_id 
        ) as t1 on t.subscription_id=t1.subscription_id
where t1.max_diff<=1;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> id    subscription_id  start_date
> 1   11             2022-01-01 00:00:00
> 2   11             2022-01-02 00:00:00
> 3   12             2022-01-01 00:00:00
> 4   12             2022-01-01 12:00:00
> ```

The subquery returns:

```
subscription_id max_diff
   11              1
   12              0
   13              2
```

which is used on the where condition.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c90df8e5db86c54fe354659c48fa73d3)

Comment: This is great--thanks!  It's not returning everything we need (for instance the rows that started this project are not returned when we run this query) but it looks to be a great start so we'll continue massaging it until we feel its 100% and then I'll update this post with what we end up with.  Thanks again!